# How to add or use .DDL file in netbeans platform app

Tags: java, embedded-resource, ddl, netbeans-platform

I'm making App in Netbeans platform in Java Swing. I want to add and use .DDL file in my App's module.

How can I do that?

Comment: In what sense DYM *"use .DDL file"* - what does 'use' entail?

Comment: in my App i capture image using X-Ray gun machine.and  for captured image code is made in vc++.i also make wrapper .DDl file for capture image in using JNI. when i run this java class file in simple JAva Application  its work well. but i want to use it in my netbeans platform App's module. so how can i add .DDL file in netbeans platform APP's module?

Comment: Is that `.DDI` or `.DDL` (*a sub-set of SQL*)?  The devil is in the details.

Comment: how to make .jar file which contain .DDL file ?

Comment: @madth3  That was my first thought, but the OP seems quite insistent.  I cannot see what a Data Definition Language has to do with anything else mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make .jar file which contain .DDL file?

Add it to a Jar that is on the run-time class-path of the app.  Here is a Netbeans tutorial for [adding an image](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#package) - the process is much the same for any non source file.

Access the file by `URL` or `InputStream`.  Here is an example of getting an URL.

```
URL urlToResource = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.ddl");
```

Answer (score 1):

The mention of VC++ and JNI makes me think you are talking about a .DLL file.
In that case, it seems there is [a simple solution](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNativeLibraries).